# Deja dup can't restore files after ubuntu 17.10 upgrade

Tags: backup, 17.10, deja-dup, duplicity

Situation: Have backups from before 17.10 upgrade, and want to restore a file or two from those backups.

When you go to Deja Dup to restore a file you don't get a choice as to where to restore from.  [You click on the restore button and either nothing happens or it just say](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2NGc.png)s "Restore from Where?", says "Backup Location" and then nothing is clickable in the window.

This is the same issue as 981272, but I can't add a comment saying I have the problem also, I can only provide an answer which seems counter-intuitive/productive to a discussion forum.

Attached is a screen shot:

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using a NAS drive for back-up:

1. Open Files application (i.e. the Ubuntu file manager)
2. Select 'Other Locations'
3. Select your backup NAS drive
4. Right-click on the folder/share you use for backups on your NAS and select 'Mount' (the share/folder will now appear in your favourites/shortcuts)
5. Open Backups application (i.e. Deja-dup)
6. Select 'Storage location'
7. In  dropdown list for 'Storage location' select 'Local folder' then select 'Choose folder'.
8. Navigate to 'Other Locations' and then the folder/share you mounted at step 4.  Select any relevant subfolder you stored your backup in previously.
9. Select 'Overview' from menu and then select 'Restore'
10. The 'Restore from Where?' dialog box should show the folder you selected at Step 8.  If not select 'Choose Folder' and then navigate to required folder.
11. Select 'Forward.'  You should now be at a point where you can restore.

I too found this process counter-intuitive; as did the poster of this similar question: [Duplicity - storage location not available, waiting for Google](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029774/duplicity-storage-location-not-available-waiting-for-google).