# Duplicity - storage location not available, waiting for Google

Tags: backup, restore, storage, duplicity

I recently upgraded Ubuntu from 17.10 to 18.04 LTS and used my usb key as a backup for my files. Now that I am on Ubuntu 18.04, I have a problem with duplicity. In fact, when I run the restore process, the restore windows says "STORAGE LOCATION NOT AVAILABLE, Waiting for Google to be configured in your backup settings..."
and then nothing happens.
Can you help me please?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Well I found the solution myself, I just had to change the location of the backup from the Storage Location in the Backup settings

Comment: Congratulations. Don't forget to accept your own answer by clicking the check mark next to it. This lets other users know the answer works. Additionally you can improve your answer with screen shots and steps on how to get to the Backup Settings screen.

Comment: I also don't get any information from the answer.

Answer (score 7):

This happen in some `Ubuntu` versions like `18.04`, the main storage for backup is Google Drive, so without any configs it shows :

```
** Storage location not available **
Waiting for Google to be configured in your backup settings...
```

So for solve this issue close the pop-up window and click on `Storage location` on the window of `backups` application, then configure storage location, I prefer to local, anybody have any ideas, settle it.

Answer (score 0):

Updating the storage location fixed this for me.  I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 and have an external 4TB hdd that is used for backups.  That 4TB hdd is encrypted and cannot be mounted without entering a password.  Somehow the Duplicity Backups app chose the parent 4TB drive itself as the backup location, instead of the location that is valid after entering the encryption password.